# Error in uploading images and storing url in database php

Tags: php

I am trying to upload photos to a specific folder and also storing their url to database but I am getting a problem of undefined index!

This is the code that is used to upload images

```
$time = time();
    $_SESSION['storeid'] = 11;
    $target_dir = "uploads/store/products/";
    $target_file1 = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["productimages1"]["name"]) . $_SESSION['storeid'] . $time;
    $target_file2 = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["productimages2"]["name"]) . $_SESSION['storeid'] . $time;
    $target_file3 = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["productimages3"]["name"]) . $_SESSION['storeid'] . $time;
    $uploadOk = 1;

    $imageFileType1 = pathinfo($target_file1,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $imageFileType2 = pathinfo($target_file2,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $imageFileType3 = pathinfo($target_file3,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["productimages1"]["tmp_name"] . $_SESSION['storeid'] . $time, $target_file1);

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["productimages1"]["tmp_name"] . $_SESSION['storeid'] . $time, $target_file2);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["productimages1"]["tmp_name"] . $_SESSION['storeid'] . $time, $target_file3);

    $image1=basename( $_FILES["productimages1"]["name"] . $_SESSION['storeid'] . $time,".jpg");
    $image2=basename( $_FILES["productimages2"]["name"] . $_SESSION['storeid'] . $time,".jpg");
    $image3=basename( $_FILES["productimages3"]["name"] . $_SESSION['storeid'] . $time,".jpg");
```

and html is

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="file" name="productimages1[]" id="product1" /> 
<input type="file" name="productimages2[]" id="product1" /> 
<input type="file" name="productimages3[]" id="product1" />
</form>
```

Can anyone look upon what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

1. Add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form.

   ```
   <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   ...
   ...
   </form>
   ```
2. In php, as your are store your files for an array for multiple upload, use loop. like:

   ```
   $time = time();
   $_SESSION['storeid'] = 11;
   $target_dir = "uploads/store/products/";

   if(!empty($_FILES["productimages1"])){
     foreach($_FILES["productimages1"] as $image1){
      if(!empty($image1['tmp_name'])){
         $target_file1 = $target_dir . basename($image1["name"]) . $_SESSION['storeid'] . $time;
         move_uploaded_file($image1["tmp_name"] . $_SESSION['storeid'] . $time, $target_file1);
      }
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: Your code does not work with above form. Check the input fields names, productimages1[], productimages2[], productimages3[]. But you are trying to loop productimages1. It will not work.So you have to customize HTML form too.

Answer (score 0):

Check this,

```
  <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $time = time();
        $_SESSION['storeid'] = 11;

        $target_dir = "uploads/store/products/";
        $target_file1 = $target_dir . $_SESSION['storeid'] . $time.$_FILES["productimages1"]["name"];
        $target_file2 = $target_dir . $_SESSION['storeid'] . $time.$_FILES["productimages2"]["name"];
        $target_file3 = $target_dir . $_SESSION['storeid'] . $time.$_FILES["productimages3"]["name"];

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["productimages1"]["tmp_name"], $target_file1);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["productimages2"]["tmp_name"], $target_file2);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["productimages3"]["tmp_name"], $target_file3);

     }
    ?>


<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="productimages1" id="product1" /> 
    <input type="file" name="productimages2" id="product1" /> 
    <input type="file" name="productimages3" id="product1" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

Added `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form. This is required when you  upload files to server.

Comment: Still undefined index!